# extract json array data from json column in postgres

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

Can anyone help me how to extract the json array data which is stored in column "TimeCounterTotals" from this select query?? when I am passing hard coded data to json_to_recordset function, it works fine but how to do in select query?

```
select "CompanyId", json_to_recordset("TimeCounterTotals") as x("TimeTotal" decimal, "TimeCounterId" varchar)
from "TimeCalculationAndApprovals" where "TimeCounterTotals" is not null limit 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want, but as a start:

```
create table json_test(id integer, fld_json json);
insert into json_test values (1, '[{"a":1,"b":"foo"},{"a":2,"b":"bar"}]'::json), (2, '[{"a":3,"b":"test"},{"a": 4,"b":"test2"}]'::json); 

select id, a, b from json_test, json_to_recordset(json_test.fld_json) as x(a integer, b varchar);
 id | a |   b   
----+---+-------
  1 | 1 | foo
  1 | 2 | bar
  2 | 3 | test
  2 | 4 | test2
```